# CMake cannot find header only file by using include_directories

Tags: c++, cmake

My file structure is as the following

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── B
│   └── core
│       └── b.h
├── bench_mark.cpp
├── data
│   └── data.h
├── A
│   ├── a.hpp
```

Within the CMakeLists.txt I include the directories as the following command

```
include_directories(./A)
include_directories(./B/core)
include_directories(./data)

add_executable(bench ./bench_mark.cpp)
```

The problem is that, in the benck_mark.cpp file, I only include the header file a.hpp like the following and everything can work well.

```
//bench_mark.cpp
#include "a.hpp"
```

The problem is that when I include another header file from b.h, the IDE told me that it cannot find the target header file.

```
// a.hpp
#include "b.h" // Works well

// b.h
#include "data.h" // cannot find the header file
```

Actually, I can compile and run my program well. My problem is that the IDE cannot find the header file and then I cannot leverage the convenience from IDE. I think the problem is that the IDE believes the file b.h is not included in any project. Because b.h is not included directly by bench_mark.cpp. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the IDE you are using?

Comment: @yurand I use Clion